# Call function in function event (onChange), from Select created in Leaflet and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet, vue-component

I am making a app in Vue.js and Leaflet.
In this app, I have a Select in leaflet created with L.DomUtil

```
  this.select = L.DomUtil.create('select','leaflet-countryselect',this.div);
```

I do not find the way for put 'v-on:change' in this 'Select', so, I have to call a event function, inside to a Function Method in Vue.js.

```
 methods: {
   firstFunction{
   },
   secondFunction() {
      this.select.on('change', function(e){
           this.firstFunction()
      }
   }
 }
```

But it not working, the error is "this.firstFunction() is not a function"

I tried to put

```
   .../
     var _self = this
     _self.firstFunction()
    ../
```

But not working, anyway.

How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use arrow function `()=>{...}` to get access to the component instance `this` as follows :

```
      secondFunction() {
          this.select.on('change', (e)=>{
            this.firstFunction()
              }
        }
```