# TypeError: Cannot read property 'details' of undefined inside foreach in Vue.js

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to set the value using this operator inside foreach loop

```
 $.each(this.form.details,(key,value)=>{

   $.each(this.form.details,(key1,value1)=>{
   this.form.details[key].total=76776;
   });
   });

 form: new Form({
   details : [{
    name:'',

  ])
  });
```

but getting this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'details' of undefined

Please suggest any solution to solve this issue.

Comment: it should be `$.each(data.details,(key,value)=>{...`

Comment: your `form` is defined inside the `data(){}` option?

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53730095/8172857?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: Yes form is inside data

Comment: please share the code containing that loop

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: Thanks it is working now, but there is issue the new value does not get retain after the foreach loop, i have added the code, Can u please check

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: Thanks it is working now, but there is issue the new value does not get retain after the foreach loop, i have added the code, Can u please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop is not necessary, the error comes from there, your inner loop uses the operator **this** that refers to the context of the first loop, which does not contain any form declared within it.
So you have to do the following

```js
$.each(this.form.details,(key,value)=>{
    this.form.details[key].total=76776;
});

 form: new Form({
   details : [{
    name:'',

  ])
  });
```

or if you need the second loop, try the following

```js
var self = this;
 $.each(this.form.details,(key,value)=>{

   $.each(self.form.details,(key1,value1)=>{
   this.form.details[key].total=76776;
   });
   });

 form: new Form({
   details : [{
    name:'',

  ])
  });
```