# "blogItems" is undefined when trying to push update to vue data variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get all the posts from firebase and add them to an array but am getting the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'blogItems' of undefined
```

here is the script:

```
  export default {
    data(){
      return{
        blogItems: []
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      this.getPosts();
    },
    methods:{

      getPosts(){

        database.collection('blog').doc('yP6aYXvisFbTsqtQ3MEfuyz6xYE3').collection('posts').get().then(snapshot =>{

          const posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
          posts.forEach(function(post){
            this.blogItems.push(post.content)
          })
        })
        
      },

    }

  }
```

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53730095/8172857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the `this` in `this.blogItems` to `posts`.

You have two ways to resolve this

1. store the this to a variable and use it

   ```
   getPosts(){
     let tis = this;

    database.collection('blog').doc('yP6aYXvisFbTsqtQ3MEfuyz6xYE3').collection('posts').get().then(snapshot =>{

      const posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
      posts.forEach(function(post){
        tis.blogItems.push(post.content)
      })
    })

    },
   ```

---

2. Using the Arrow functions

   ```
    getPosts(){

    database.collection('blog').doc('yP6aYXvisFbTsqtQ3MEfuyz6xYE3').collection('posts').get().then(snapshot =>{

      const posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
      posts.forEach((post) => {
        this.blogItems.push(post.content)
      })
    })

    },
   ```